# How can a method call like Thread.MemoryBarrier (or Monitor.Enter) change the way the compiler works?

Tags: c#, multithreading, compilation

To my understanding, using `lock` (meaning: `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`) adds full memory fences around it, for avoiding unwanted reordering of store and load operations around the critical area.

Instructions reordering can happen at the compiler level (even to MSIL). How can a method call change the way the compiler works?
For example, what happen if I do this:

```
if (Random() > 0.5)
    Monitor.Enter(lockObj);
```

Only at runtime it will be decided weather or not a memory barrier is needed, when the code is already compiled (to MSIL) and it is seemingly too late.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Consider that any 'memory barrier' is *part of* the `Monitor.Enter` operation - so, if it's not called, then *the run-time guarantees changes* wrt. access (even if such access is not jostled around before hand..) That is, without the code *always* participating, there are cases when it *might not* yield the correct/expected behavior.

Comment: (The core question seems good, the example .. perhaps not so much.)

Comment: @user2864740 One of us did not understand the other. I'm not intending to actually use the above code, it was just an example. Consider the following scenario. `flag = true; Monitor.Exit(); number = 3;`. The compiler might decide to switch between the `flag = true` and `number = 3` if it doesn't know Monitor.Exit() should be a memory barrier. This creates a thread-safety problem. How, at compile-time, should the compiler know not to do that?

Comment: Consider that any 'memory barrier' is *part of* the `Monitor.Enter` (or `Exit`) operation: it (read: any synchronization guarantees) **only** needs to be considered/applied if such code-path *is* executed; and *must* be done so in such a case.

Comment: @user2864740 I understand that. I just don't understand how it is done. Like I said, seemingly, it changes the way the compiler compiles. But the compiler doesn't know what code path will be taken.

Comment: It is similar to (eg): `if (Maybe) { lock (x) { f(y); } } else { f(y); }`, except it is splitting the Enter/Exit.

Comment: Very trivially when considering the singular operations themselves: `bool Monitor.Enter() { Thread.MemoryBarrier(/* or whatever is done */); .. }`. In this case it is not a conditional decision of the operation: the decision was to Enter/Exit.

Comment: @user2864740 This is all about runtime. I'm talking about the the _compilation_ process. Taking C# code and turning it into CIL opcodes.

Comment: See above. *The compiler doesn't [need to] make a "conditional decision"*. (A program that does not correctly use synchronization primitives is in error. This is outside the scope of compilation.)

Comment: @user2864740 So does the compiler looks specifically for the the function `Monitor.Enter` and if it sees one, it puts a memory barrier?

Comment: NO. The *compiler* emits IL to *call* Enter/Exit: `call System.Threading.Monitor.Enter`. Question might be what those methods (which can be handled as intrinsics during *JIT*) do inside.. I provided a very crude example above.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm sorry, I deeply don't understand you. Maybe we are referring different things when we say a memory barrier? What do you mean when you say a memory barrier?

Comment: Please follow along with LINQ Pad and the generated IL. What is “meant” by a memory barrier or full fence is not even relevant during compilation to MSIL: the contract is part of the Enter/Exit API, as called directly by IL. Any underlying hardware operations are handled by the runtime/JIT.

Comment: @user2864740 To my understanding it is deeply related to compilation, as compilation might reorder opcodes.

Comment: `How can a method call change the way the compiler works?` How did you come to the conclusion that this is a **compile time** issue rather than a JIT / runtime one?

Comment: @anotherasker2 **C# Compiler compiles to MSIL** -> *run-time* JIT (usually) 'compiles to' or 'otherwise invokes' machine operations preserving (IL/program) correctness ..

Comment: Just for completeness: about 5 extra comments from this discussion disappeared some why.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your thoughts are correct. `lock(x) { }` is just short for this:

```
object __lockObj = x;
bool __lockWasTaken = false;
try
{
    System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(__lockObj, ref __lockWasTaken);
    // Your code...
}
finally
{
    if (__lockWasTaken) System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(__lockObj);
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

But a `lock` does nothing to secure your memory or tell the compiler to do somehting different with the code within the braces. In the link above you find a nice small example. Here is the important part. **Both** methods use `lock (balanceLock)` so if multiple threads call one, or the other method the first thread acquire the lock and can execute the code inside the scope. The other threads are blocked as soon as the hit `lock (balanceLock)`. If the first thread leaves the scope of `lock (balanceLock)` then the next thread can acquire the lock and resume executing.

```
    public decimal Debit(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Balance before debit :{balance, 5}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Amount to remove     :{amount, 5}");
                balance = balance - amount;
                Console.WriteLine($"Balance after debit  :{balance, 5}");
                return amount;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Balance before credit:{balance, 5}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Amount to add        :{amount, 5}");
            balance = balance + amount;
            Console.WriteLine($"Balance after credit :{balance, 5}");
        }
    }
```

If you remove for example the `lock (balanceLock)` in `public void Credit(decimal amount)` than everything breaks:

```
    public decimal Debit(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (balanceLock)
        {
            if (balance >= amount)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Balance before debit :{balance, 5}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Amount to remove     :{amount, 5}");
                balance = balance - amount;
                Console.WriteLine($"Balance after debit  :{balance, 5}");
                return amount;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Balance before credit:{balance, 5}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Amount to add        :{amount, 5}");
        balance = balance + amount;
        Console.WriteLine($"Balance after credit :{balance, 5}");
    }
```

Here step by step what could happen in a multithreaded environment:

- Thread #1 calls `public decimal Debit(decimal amount)` and acquires the lock
- Thread #2 make the same call and gets blocked while acquiring the lock and all seems fine.
- But then Thread #3 calls `public void Credit(decimal amount)` and can manipulate `balance` because it never checks if there is any lock.
- Thread #1 manipulates `balance` too, and if the operation does not happen atomic then you cannot predict what the value `balance` holds after Thread #1 and #3 are done

And you need to be very careful when using locks you could end up in deadlocks very easy if you use nested locks on multiple objects.

There multiple different techniques all with there own up- and downsides.

- `lock`, `Monitor`
- `Mutex`
- `Interlocked`
- ...

If you are looking for the SpeculationBarrier feature you will find this in the `Interlocked` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.speculationbarrier?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Interlocked_SpeculationBarrier

Comment: "As we said earlier, Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit both generate full fences." Source: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx . Also, even if Monitor.Enter does not create a memory barrier, Thread.MemoryBarrier() definitely does. My question is _how_ it is done.

Comment: @anotherasker2 Download LINQ Pad, type in `lock (new object()) {}` and hit "Show IL". Note that calls into Enter/Exit remain after IL generation, even with full optimizations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean did you look into the source of mscorlib? https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs#L1787 you see that it's a exern method in the CLR. You find that described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-memorybarrier :

    LONG Barrier;
    __asm {
        xchg Barrier, eax
    }

Comment: Your answer did not touch the area of MSIL at all. That was however question of OP.